# Modifying bash prompt

Tags: bash, unix

When I open my terminal in Mac OS X, the command prompt current reads:

```
James-MacBook:project1 sam$
```

`project1` is the name of the current directory.

What I want is to display the full path instead of `James-MacBook`.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy. This is not an OS X thing, but a `bash` thing.  Try this:

```
export PS1='$(pwd): '
```

Then if you want to make it permanent, just edit your `.bash_profile`:

```
nano ~/.bash_profile
```

And place that first command in there.

Comment: While this works, there's no reason to employ a command substitution: `\w` is sufficient to represent the working directory's full path: `export PS1='\w$ '` (assumes that the prompt should end in literal `$ `).

Comment: Good point; if you don't want your home dir. represented as `~`, use `export PS1=$PWD$ ` (still no need for a command substitution :)

Answer (score 1):

Your current prompt appears to show the hostname and the basename of your current directory.  That means that the bash prompt, `PS1`, is likely set to:

```
PS1='\h:\W\$ '
```

To get the full directory name, use `\w` in place of `\W`:

```
PS1='\h:\w\$ '
```

You can set this at the command prompt.  To make it permanent, this command can go into `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` or other depending on how your system is configured.

You can read more about the options for command prompts, for which there are many options, in the `PROMPTING` section of `man bash`.  Regarding the `\w` and `\W` options mentioned above, `man bash` explains how they are used:

> \w
> the current working directory, with $HOME abbreviated with a tilde (uses the value of the PROMPT_DIRTRIM
>   variable)
>     \W
>     the basename of the current working directory, with $HOME abbreviated with a tilde

Comment: @JakeGould Note that, e.g., `~/dir` is still the "full path", not relative, and is recognized as such by shell commands.  Bash provides this shortened form because many people prefer it this way.